# Dailymotion mobile player api parameter `playerView.loadContent.startTime` has no effect

Tags: android, ios, swift, dailymotion-api

#### Description

From the dailymotion player ios offical docs: https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#embed-mobile-ios-player-methods

Player method `load​Content(video​Id:​playlist​Id:​start​Time:​)` will load content with start time if specified.

When I pass 12 to the start time parameter, the video won't start from 12 seconds. Instead it starts from 0 seconds. So the `startTime` parameter has no effect.

#### How to reproduce:

1. use [ios official sample project](https://github.com/dailymotion/player-sdk-ios-samples/blob/d0e7003f670282c7c26423541923a289069e272e/BasicExample/BasicExample/ViewController.swift)
2. make folow changes in `player-sdk-ios-samples/BasicExample/BasicExample/ViewController.swift`:

```
...
    // Add your player ID that was created in Dailymotion Partner HQ
-   Dailymotion.createPlayer(playerId: <#"xbzlf"#>, videoId: <#"x84sh87"#>, playerParameters: playerParams , playerDelegate: self) { [weak self] playerView, error in
+   Dailymotion.createPlayer(playerId: <#"xbzlf"#>, playerParameters: playerParams, playerDelegate: self) { [weak self] playerView, error in
      ...
          // Add the Player View to view hierarchy
          self.addPlayerView(playerView: playerView)
+         playerView.loadContent(videoId: "x8o0gz5", startTime: 12)
        }
      }
    }
...
```

3. run the `BasicExample` project and see whether video starts at 12 seconds

#### Additional Note

I've checked the folowing api won't starts at `startTime`:

- native ios `playerView.loadContent` with [start time parameter](https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#embed-mobile-ios-player-methods)
- native android `player.loadContent` with [start time parameter](https://developers.dailymotion.com/native-android-sdk-pre-release/#android-sdk-player-methods)